# How to Convert .wmv to .mp4 using Command-Line?

Tags: android, windows, mp4, wmv, video-conversion

I need a windows console application which convert .wmv to .mp4 file. I am looking for this for 2 days, no luck. I need coverted video to support "progressive" download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried MEncoder?  I haven't tried those particular formats myself, but MEncoder is pretty versatile.

http://kovensky.project357.com/

Here's a post where someone is trying to do what you are doing with MEncoder:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=103834

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try [FFmpeg for windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).
And check [a thread where all this has been discussed](https://superuser.com/questions/73529/how-to-convert-wmv-to-mp4)

Also I could suggest the use of [MEncoder](http://wiki.quakeworld.nu/Mencoder_howto), wich would convert about any format to any other one!

Comment: YES, look at the "thread where all this has been discussed" link, someone wrote explicitly "to encode WMV to MP4" with the example bellow

Comment: Anyway, did you try the command? ffmpeg is not supporting .wmv files. And consider my edit. I need progressive download.

Comment: Anyway, just downloaded the FFmpeg for windows and successfully converted a .wmv video with it. Considering your edit after my answer... I'm not sure about progressive download.

Answer (score -2):

WinFF has a simple interface and keeps the confusing choices to a minimum, while offering the powerful option of converting as many files as you can throw at it in one batch.
[Video Converter for Mac](http://www.iphone-mac.com/video-converter-for-mac.html) is the best Mac Video Converter tool to convert videos on Mac OS X. It converts video among formats such as:

- MKV
- MPEG
- MP4
- 3GP
- 3G2
- MOV
- AVI
- DV
- MTS
- M2TS
- TiVo
- TS
- TP
- TRP
- M2T
- VOB

I Hope it helps.